# Zip some files then zip the zip Node js

Tags: node.js, zip

I need to automate some process, and first grab some files into a zip and then this zip should be also zipped. I'm using node archiver, but the code I wrote does not work.

```
function zip(name, files, path, callback) {

    let output = fs.createWriteStream(name + '.zip'),
        archive = archiver('zip', {store: true});

    output.on('close', () => {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    }); 

    archive.on('error', err => {
        throw err;
    });

    archive.pipe(output);

    if(files.constructor === Array) 
        files.forEach((e, i) => {
            archive.append(fs.createReadStream(path + e), {name: e});
        });
    else 
         archive.append(fs.createReadStream(path + files), {name: files});

    archive.finalize();

    if(callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
fs.readFile(widgetPath + widgetFileName + '.manifest', 'utf8', (err, json) => {

    let jsonData = JSON.parse(json),
        name = jsonData.name;

    return zip(name, [fileJS, fileManifest, fileHtml], widgetPath,
         zip(name, name + '.zip', './'));

});
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: There is zip in zip, but I cannot get the files inside second zip.

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling the callback parameter properly from your return line.

Try changing this:

```
return zip(name, [fileJS, fileManifest, fileHtml], widgetPath,
     zip(name, name + '.zip', './'));
```

To this:

```
return zip(name, [fileJS, fileManifest, fileHtml], widgetPath,
     () => zip(name, name + '.zip', './'));
```

In the first case you are calling the inner `zip` call so it can return a value to be passed to the outer `zip` call. Since `zip` does not return anything it will result in `undefined`, which is why there are no errors reported.